# Adobe Brackets - Finding the values of .useTabChar .tabSize and .spaceUnits

Tags: adobe-brackets

I can't figure out how to access these values found in Editor.js.
I've seen them elsewhere as `.getUseTabChar()`, `.getTabSize()`, and `.getSpaceUnits()`

My [extension](https://github.com/zeffii/Precursor) would benefit being able to get that kind of information. Right now I can find this information with _codeMirror , but from what i've read and seen in Brackathon talks this is considered deprecated.

```
var editor = EditorManager.getActiveEditor();
console.log(editor._codeMirror.options.indentUnit);
console.log(editor._codeMirror.options.indentWithTabs);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brackets Sprint 36 (which is within the next few days, as I write this), includes a new preferences manager. [There's a section about this](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Write-Extensions#wiki-working-with-preferences) on the wiki. You should be able to do something like this:

```
var PreferencesManager = brackets.getModule("preferences/PreferencesManager");

// Whenever you need the current value
PreferencesManager.get("spaceUnits");

// If you need to know when the value might have changed:
PreferencesManager.getPreference("spaceUnits").on("change", function () {
    var newValue = PreferencesManager.get("spaceUnits");
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This covers my needs nicely and explains it more concisely than the example on the wiki (Which somehow didn't connect the dots for me).

Comment: I guess I'll have to wait :)